# Gazebo: Could not load controller, JointTrajectoryController does not exist (Mastering ROS chapter 10)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am new in ROS, and I was reading a book "Mastering ROS".
But I am having an issue with loading controllers in Gazebo, from chapter 10. Working with perception using MoveIt! and Gazebo. Even though I just copied code from the repo. (Actually, the same issue appeared on chapter 3 or 4).
Logs are following:

```
[ERROR] [1486485132.488395779, 0.283000000]: Could not load controller 'seven_dof_arm_joint_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1486485132.488718126, 0.283000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[INFO] [1486485132.533815, 0.295000]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller
[ERROR] [1486485133.491534, 0.560000]: Failed to load seven_dof_arm_joint_controller
[INFO] [1486485133.494729, 0.560000]: Loading controller: gripper_controller
[ERROR] [1486485133.520919999, 0.566000000]: Could not load controller 'gripper_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1486485133.521358891, 0.566000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[ERROR] [1486485134.523407, 1.095000]: Failed to load gripper_controller
```

I think, it is because I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic, whereas in the book the system was 14.04 and Indigo.

How can I resolve this issue? Any ideas?

EDIT1: I changed some urdf files because I had same issue as [here](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/issues/11)

UPD: I've resolved it by installing all available controllers: `sudo apt-get install ros*controller*`

I know, it is not the right way, but somehow I couldn't find anywhere that I can install joint controller itself `sudo apt-get ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller`. Maybe it was too obvious. I found it in the new packages list when I ran the command above.

`The following NEW packages will be installed: ros-kinetic-bhand-controller ros-kinetic-diff-drive-controller ros-kinetic-dynamixel-controllers ros-kinetic-dynamixel-driver ros-kinetic-dynamixel-msgs ros-kinetic-dynamixel-sdk ros-kinetic-dynamixel-workbench-controllers ros-kinetic-dynamixel-workbench-msgs ros-kinetic-dynamixel-workbench-toolbox ros-kinetic-force-torque-sensor-controller ros-kinetic-gripper-action-controller ros-kinetic-imu-sensor-controller ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller ros-kinetic-kobuki-controller-tutorial ros-kinetic-md49-base-controller ros-kinetic-md49-messages ros-kinetic-md49-serialport ros-kinetic-nav-pcontroller ros-kinetic-robot-controllers ros-kinetic-robot-controllers-interface ros-kinetic-robot-controllers-msgs ros-kinetic-robotis-controller-msgs ros-kinetic-ros-controllers ros-kinetic-rqt-controller-manager ros-kinetic-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller ros-kinetic-velocity-controllers ros-kinetic-view-controller-msgs ros-kinetic-yocs-diff-drive-pose-controller ros-kinetic-yocs-safety-controller`

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254084/gazebo:-could-not-load-controller,-jointtrajectorycontroller-does-not-exist-(mastering-ros-chapter-10)/) by [saken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29297/saken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've resolved it by installing all available controllers: `sudo apt-get install ros*controller*`

Maybe, it is not the right way, because you don't really find a missing dependency in this way.
But somehow I couldn't find anywhere that I can just install joint controller itself:
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller`

---

Originally posted by [saken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29297/saken/) with karma: 161 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-08**:
If this is really a problem with the way the package(s) list their dependencies (and thus make `rosdep` not work), it would be nice if you could report that on the issue tracker of the book.

**Comment by [saken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29297/saken/) on 2017-02-09**:
I see, thanks!

**Comment by [Cabbage](https://answers.ros.org/users/32159/cabbage/) on 2017-10-06**:
It works, thank you.

**Comment by [Meric](https://answers.ros.org/users/40534/meric/) on 2019-10-07**:
This answer works but why do I install all these controllers?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-07**:
You don't need to install *all* controllers. Just the ones that are used.